# How to add a custom CSS class to core blocks in Gutenberg editor?

Tags: filters, css, javascript, block-editor

I'm trying to add a class to list blocks (`core/list`) in Gutenberg. Unfortunately, it looks like because some blocks like lists and paragraphs don't have the standard default class name of `wp-block-{name}` they can't be renamed using the [`blocks.getBlockDefaultClassName`](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/extensibility/extending-blocks/#blocks-getblockdefaultclassname) filter.

To get around that, I've used the `blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps` filter, which seems to enable me to add a class to ALL the blocks that don't already have classes. Code below is how I got that working. It's adding `added-class-name` to blocks likes lists and paragraphs and so on.

```
function addBlockClassName( className ) {
  return Object.assign( className, { class: 'added-class-name' } );
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
  'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps',
  'gdt-guten-plugin/add-block-class-name',
  addBlockClassName
);
```

And I'm enqueuing it like so:

```
function gdt_blocks_class_rename() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
      'gdt-plugin-blacklist-blocks',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/guten-addons.js',
      array( 'wp-blocks' )
  );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'gdt_blocks_class_rename' );
```

However, what I want to be able to do is add a class to *ONLY* list blocks? Can that be done at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's motion to [potentially add this class by default](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/42269) in a future version of WordPress.

If you only need to add a class on the front-end of the site (the editor already has `wp-block-list` on list blocks), you can do this with PHP and the [WP_HTML_Tag_Processor class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_html_tag_processor/) (new in WordPress 6.2) via the [`render_block` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/).

```
<?php
add_filter( 'render_block', 'wpse308021_add_class_to_list_block', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Polyfill wp-block-list class on list blocks
 *
 * Should not be necessary in future version of WP:
 * @see https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12420
 * @see https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/42269
 */
function wpse308021_add_class_to_list_block( $block_content, $block ) {

    if ( 'core/list' === $block['blockName'] ) {
        $block_content = new WP_HTML_Tag_Processor( $block_content );
        $block_content->next_tag(); /* first tag should always be ul or ol */
        $block_content->add_class( 'wp-block-list' );
        $block_content->get_updated_html();
    }

    return $block_content;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You have second and third arguments with this hook you can use the second to get the block type.

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/extensibility/extending-blocks/

> A filter that applies to all blocks returning a WP Element in the save
>   function. This filter is used to add extra props to the root element
>   of the save function. For example: to add a className, an id, or any
>   valid prop for this element. **It receives the current props of the save
>   element, the block type and the block attributes as arguments.**

```
function addBlockClassName( props, blockType ) {
    if(blockType.name === 'core/list') {
        return Object.assign( props, { class: 'wp-block-list' } );
    }
    return props;
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps',
    'gdt-guten-plugin/add-block-class-name',
    addBlockClassName
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `class: 'wp-block-list'` be `className: 'wp-block-list'`? Also, there is now a `blocks.getBlockDefaultClassName` filter. 
@see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getblockdefaultclassname

Answer (score 4):

There are issues in the answer marked as correct. It will break the alignment class functionality, and is not actually adding to the classList, instead it is overriding it. And you will only be able to use that one solution for your whole theme.

Instead you can use "registerBlockStyle()" to add a style variation to the list block, and set "isDefault" to true for it to use that class/style but still be able to skip using it, or add a multiple variations if you want.

the wp.domReady() makes sure that it loads when it should and applies the changes

```
wp.domReady( () => {
  wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/list', {
    name: 'custom-list-style',
    label: 'Custom list style',
    isDefault: true
  } );
} );
```

Comment: I agree. While the original answer does "work", you are right it can cause issues. If you try to add another class latter to your the WP editor baulks and things break. I've switched to using Block Styles as well now.