# Simple way to add custom class and ids to individual Gutenberg blocks

Tags: css, html, block-editor

Is there a simple way to add classnames to individual core Gutenberg blocks?

Blocks is a great step toward moving to a web where HTML structurally/functionally describes elements, which are styled elsewhere in CSS. However, this is limited in that blocks cannot be easily classed?

I'd be happy with a plugin that extends existing (or custom) block functionality to include classes and ids.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom class to core blocks in Gutenberg](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308021/add-custom-class-to-core-blocks-in-gutenberg)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The referenced article asks how to add permanent classes to core blocks at the code level. I was asking how to add classes dynamically from the admin interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every block has a field for custom CSS classes in the 'Advanced' panel:

[image]