# Add a containing DIV to core Gutenberg blocks

Tags: customization, block-editor

The design I am working with calls for each Gutenberg block to have a coloured background (white in this case) with `max-width: 1160px` and the content within to have `max-width: 800px` and centered. Similar to the image below:

[image]

Which would need a setup like this:

```
<main class="site-background">
    <div class="width-1160">
        <p class="width-800">Some text content...</p>
    </div>
</main>
```

At this time we are only using core Gutenberg blocks but the markup it produces is similar to the below, without the containing `<div>`:

```
<main class="site-background">
    <p class="width-800">Some text content...</p>
</main>
```

Is there a way to add a containing `<div>` to all Gutenberg content blocks that will be safe when core updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are other ways e.g. with CSS only or [Add custom class to core blocks in Gutenberg](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/308044/26350), but regarding:

> Add a containing DIV to core Gutenberg blocks

one way could be with the `render_block` filter:

```
add_filter( 'render_block', function( $block_content, $block ) {
    // Target core/* and core-embed/* blocks.
    if ( preg_match( '~^core/|core-embed/~', $block['blockName'] ) ) {
       $block_content = sprintf( '<div class="some__class">%s</div>', $block_content );
    }
    return $block_content;
}, PHP_INT_MAX - 1, 2 );
```

to div-wrap the core blocks on the frontend.

Changing the HTML layout might affect the current style of the site.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick. We have what appears to be a complicated layout that needs to work with Gutenberg where main blocks have a background-color but will have stand-out/feature quotes in-between content that will have a transparent background. It's the only solution I can think of at this time.

Comment: Glad to hear it was somewhat helpful.