# Gutenberg table block with Bootstrap .table class

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor, twitter-bootstrap, table

On my frontend I am using Boostrap 4, however Gutenberg block table has class `<table class="wp-block-table">` so instead of creating new table style it would make more sense to append the Boostrap table class to `wp-block-table` class. Would like to know if this possible. Thanks.

Comment: You can extend blocks to add the class to every table block. I'll refer to this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/308044/81939 as it's explained there

If you want the class just to be added to a single block you can use the built-in solution explained here https://technicalsupport.blog/2019/01/04/how-to-add-a-custom-css-class-to-gutenberg-blocks/

Comment: Check https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-bootstrap-blocks/ they have implemented classes for container row and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my theme did not recognize wp block table class I have added table Sass class from Gutenberg to my theme.

```
.wp-block-table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 240px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 24px;

  td, th {
    padding: .3em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  th {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good solution is to add this to functions.php of your theme (taken [from there](https://napitwptech.com/tutorial/wordpress-development/integrate-bootstrap-responsive-table-wordpress/)):

```
function theme_prefix_bootstrap_responsive_table( $content ) {
    $content = str_replace(
        [ '<table>', '</table>' ],
        [ '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-responsive">', '</table>' ],
        $content
    );

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_prefix_bootstrap_responsive_table' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables were not showing with the Wordpress Magazinely theme.

Adding this code (from Benjamin Franklyn above) worked for me. Add it to Apperance -> Customize -> Additional CSS

```css
.wp-block-table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 240px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 24px;

  td, th {
    padding: .3em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  th {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you nest the CSS selectors like that?

Answer (score -1):

You can add `.table` as the class under the "block settings" for the table block. You can also add additional classes such as `.table-bordered` and `.table-styled`. All table class references can be found in the [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/).

[image: gutenberg-class]

Comment: The classes on that field will get added to the `<figure class="wp-block...` and **not** on the `<table>` inside it.